# How to save ggplots in PDF with less size R?

Tags: r, pdf, ggplot2

I am having trouble saving numerous ggplots inside pdf because I am creating ggplots (scatter plots and boxplots) with 12 million rows (lots of observations).

The problem is when I save the plot as PDF using:

```
ggsave("my_plots.pdf", myArrangedPlots)
```

The pdf size is very large = 90 MB for only 120 pages of PDF

When I save one plot as PNG using:

```
ggsave("plot1.png" plot1)
```

The size is much less in comparison to saving same single plot in PDF (1MB vs 0.1 MBs)

I think the reason is that ggplot internal mechanism tries to save the plots in Vectorized format format inside the PDF file to get maximum resolution but I don't need that much of resolution. Also note that when there are million of points represented in Vectorized format the size is going to be greater than the same plot in PNG, because PNG doesn't save layers.

**I want to save the plots in PDF format but embedding the plots as PNGs instead of Vectorized format  to make the PDF file size smaller.**

I there any parameter in ggplot2 to achieve this or is there any workaround?

Comment: yes, just corrected it, thank you @RichardTelford

Comment: Use rmarkdown to create a PDF document with embedded images.

Comment: Your instinct is right but SVG has nothing to do with it. PDF is also a vectorized format for images - when a graph is saved as PDF, all points are encoded and saved.

Comment: @GregorThomas thanks for your comment. I would like to achieve this using .R file so I can run it every x days using cronjobs, using Rmarkdwon is the last option

Comment: Why do you think  Rmarkdown would be harder than .R to run with cronjobs?

Comment: @GregorThomas yes, just checked it how to do it, you are right

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Observing the documentation of **pdf()**, it's parameters seem to be compatible with **ggsave()**.

I found a parameter which is **useDingbats**, by default it is set to FALSE but If you set it to **TRUE**, the PDF size reduces drastically from 94 MB to 10 MB in my case.

So I use it like this:

```
ggsave("myplots.pdf", arrangedPlots, useDingbats = TRUE)
```

NOTE: setting useDingbats to true what does is using Dinbats font for small circles, which in case of the scatter plots and boxplots with lots of outlier points reduces the size of final PDF a lot.